# TOC summary in the header of each slide

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, beamer

There is the [list of possible R-Markdown templates](https://hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix/) for `beamer_presentation` in R-Markdown.

And most of them include a kind of a "Navigation bar" at the top (or left/right) of each slide, like that:

[image: Example of slider header]

While I do understand how to create a TOC in R-Markdown (by providing a `toc: true` in the header, I cannot figure out how to add this navigation to each slide.

I also understand how to create a floating TOC for the R-Markdown for HTML format (via `toc_float: true` as it is described [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html#table-of-contents)) but still cannot figure out how to make it in a `beamer` format. Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Try to add `\usetheme{Antibes}` to your header includes

Comment: Or if you just want the headline without all the other stylistic elements `\useoutertheme{tree}` (you might have to adjust colours to make it visible)

Comment: btw: the image of your avatar is soooooo cute!

Comment: Thanks! The solution was that simple, I am ashamed. And thanks for the avatar :)

Comment: You're welcome! Could you please write a short self-answer to your identical question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/514031/toc-summary-in-the-header-of-each-slide to make sure no user wastes time to try to solve an already solved problem?

Comment: @samcarter : just deleted it for simplicity. Thanks again! (and the GREAT work with the tikz duck!)

Comment: Oh, thanks for your kind works about the tikzducks! Do you know that there is also a tikzpig, albeit not as cute as your user image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The headline with the navigation bar is automatically inserted in every frame if you use a suitable beamer theme. The one you show in your questions is called `Antibes`

```
---
title: test title
output:
  beamer_presentation:
    theme: "Antibes"
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{tikzlings}
---

# Section name

## Subsection name

### Slide 1

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pig[scale=2]
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]